# How do you enter quote characters in C# 6.0 string interpolations

Tags: c#, string-interpolation, c#-6.0

Given

```
IDictionary<string, string> x;
```

previously you could do (as an example of the parameter code having quote marks):

```
string.Format("{0}", x["y"]);
```

What is the proper way to format the C# 6.0 string interpolation?

```
$"{x["y"]}"   // compiler error due to the quotes on the indexer value
              // UPDATE:  actually does work, must have had another typo I missed
```

Escaping the quotes as

```
\"
```

doesn't work, and doing

```
 var b = "y";
 ...
 $"{x[b]}"
```

seems awkward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var dictionary= new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary.Add("x","value of x");
Console.WriteLine($"x is {dictionary["x"]}");
```

Make sure your project is set to use the version 6.0 of C# Language level (it's the default option on VS2015).

Edit: You can also try it [here](http://volatileread.com/utilitylibrary/snippetcompiler?id=20824). (make sure you check the "C# 6.0 Beta").

Comment: Hmmm.. when I retested it, it worked fine.  I must be typoing badly before coffee.

Comment: Even this works: `$"x is { new Dictionary<string, string> {["x"] = "value of x" }["x"]}"`